Explosion of LiMnO2 Battery Cell
I am working on a battery pack consisting of 10 non-rechargeable LiMnO₂ battery cells, size A (50 mm x 17 mm), configured in a 5S2P arrangement as shown in the schematic below. The schematic also includes the protection circuit:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The Issue:
One of the cells in the battery pack (BAT21) exploded.
Investigations Conducted:
I have conducted an initial investigation into the battery pack with the following observations:

The BMB (Battery Management Board) indicated that the pack was over-discharged, which was also confirmed by the voltages of other cells.

All protection diodes, fuses, and the BMB appear to be functioning correctly.

The battery pack case shows no signs of pressure buildup, overheating, or mechanical damage.

It is possible that the battery pack was past its expiration date, but I cannot confirm this definitively.


Tests Performed:
To replicate the failure, I conducted the following tests on other cells from the pack:

Charging a cell without protection (no failure observed).
Over-discharging a cell without protection (no failure observed).
Overheating a cell while discharging (no failure observed).
Submerging a cell in water (no failure observed).
Impact testing on the pack (no failure observed).

Despite these tests, I have not been able to replicate the explosion.
Request for Assistance:
I am seeking advice or suggestions on how to determine the root cause of the cell explosion. Are there any additional tests or investigation methods I should consider to pinpoint the issue?
Thanks for the time and insights!

(Any chance of cell reversal as opposed to cell voltage reversal?)

I think it’s unlikely, as the reverse polarity diode (D21) appears to be functioning correctly. However, the issue could potentially be due to a loose connection with D21. I checked other connections, and the welds were very good, so I think it’s not likely.

I’d suggest you contact the cell manufacturer.

What diodes are used?

You state, "Over-discharging a cell without protection (no failure observed)." The issue, as @greybeard implies, is that when cells are placed in series, in a battery, as the battery discharges, one or more cells may have electricity forced through in reverse polarity.
For example, consider three Li-ion cells (though this applies to any battery chemistry, including  Leclanché, Ni-Fe, NiMH and Pb-acid), with actual capacities of 1.0 A-h, 1.0 A-h and 0.9 A-h, with variation due to manufacturing tolerances or aging. All are initially all at 4 V.
After 0.9 A-h is withdrawn, the voltage on each of the first two cells, according to this chart, is ~3.0 V... but the last cell is ~1.7 V! The first two cells can keep pushing current through the third, down to zero V, then attempting to charge it in reverse.
The diode across each cell will prevent reverse-voltage exceeding the diode forward voltage drop, Vf (which I do  not see in the question). However, reverse charging a LiMnO₂ cell to -0.2 V (using a Schottky diode) or, worse, -0.7 V (ordinary Si diode Vf) might be the cause of the burst cell.
A battery-management board (such as this example for Li-ion chemistry) should prevent over-discharge, and subsequent reverse charge.
